# maven-javadoc-plugin latest version issue

Tags: java, maven, maven-javadoc-plugin

I am using maven-javadoc-plugin 3.0.1(latest version). When I try to generate site information (project reports and etc), the javadoc does not show links to the dependent classes. All I see is full class name and no linkage. When I use maven-javadoc-plugin 2.10.4, everything works fine.

Using maven 3.2.5 and java 8.

Ran "mvn clean site -P profileID -X" for both versions of maven-javadoc-plugin and noticed below in the output:

1. Case 3.0.1

[

```
[INFO] Generating "Javadoc" report              maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.1:javadoc 
[DEBUG] Trying to add links for dependencies...
[ERROR] ProjectBuildingException xxxx: Error resolving project artifact:
```

2. Case 2.10.4

[

```
[DEBUG] Trying to add links for dependencies...
[DEBUG] Using mirror central-mirror XXX for central XXX.
[DEBUG] Connection request: [route: {}->XXX][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
[DEBUG] Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {}->XXX][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[DEBUG] Connecting to XXX
[DEBUG] CookieSpec selected: best-match
[DEBUG] Auth cache not set in the context
[DEBUG] Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[DEBUG] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[DEBUG] Attempt 1 to execute request
[DEBUG] Sending request: GET /snapshot-site/...
```

My observations:
In 3.0.1 case, the plugin fails to retrieve the information from the correct repo. In 2.10.4 case, the Sending request was having the correct snapshot-site url.

Comment: Can you give the latest SNAPSHOT a try? (it contains over 40 resolved issues) Easiest way is probably to download https://github.com/apache/maven-javadoc-plugin and run `mvn install`

Comment: Thanks for the link and suggestion, but unfortunately the latest snapshot version isn't working too.

Comment: consider creating an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAVADOC

Comment: And please ensure to attach a minimal project to reproduce the issue